# Call a Stored Procedure to perform Count on an array

Tags: mysql, vb.net, stored-procedures

I am selecting a `distinct user` from `IT_Cases_List` and *stored it* in an `arraystaff()`.
From this array, I will then call a `Stored Procedure` *to count the no of cases attended by this user*,`(arraystaff(i))` and loop it until arraystaff.length-1

but the problem is that the count does not tally.

```
Sub getStaff(ByVal month As String)
    If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        con.Open()
    End If
    Dim s As String = "select distinct Attended_by from IT_Cases_List where month(Resolution_date) ='" & month & "' "
    s = s & "And Year(Resolution_date) ='" & ddyear.SelectedValue & "' and Attended_by is not null "
    cmd = New SqlCommand(s, con)
    da = New SqlDataAdapter
    ds = New DataSet
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    da.Fill(ds)
    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        staffcount = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
        ReDim arrstaff(staffcount - 1)
        For Me.i = 0 To staffcount - 1
            arrstaff(i) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("Attended_by")
        Next
            getCases()
     End If
End Sub

Sub getCases()
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        con.Open()
    End If

    ReDim arrdata(arrstaff.Length - 1, 0)
    For Me.i = 0 To arrstaff.Length - 1
        cmd = New SqlCommand("get_cases", con)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ename", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = arrstaff(i)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Yr", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddyear.SelectedValue
        cmd.Parameters.Add("month", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = m

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        da = New SqlDataAdapter()
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        ds = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)

        If Not IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("NoCase")) Then
            arrdata(i, 0) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("NoCase")
        End If
    Next

    cmd = New SqlCommand("delete from cases_Temp", con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

and this is my stored procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[get_cases](
@Ename  varchar(100),
@Yr varchar(50),
@month varchar(30))

 AS
BEGIN
declare @NoCase as int

select @NoCase=COUNT(*)
from IT_Cases_List
where Attended_by= @Ename and month(Resolution_date) =@month and 
Year(Resolution_date)=@Yr and Attended_by is not null 


insert into cases_temp(Ename,NoCase)
values(@Ename,@NoCase)

select * from cases_Temp

end
```

i don't know what have i done wrong.
any help will be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

ok, i've called only once `getcases` but i'm still having the same problem.

this is what i get when i run the program:

[image: http://imgur.com/dkhmU]

if i get Count(*) from the database, the total no of cases i should be getting is 132, whereas the total of cases i get from the program is 157 (7+7+20+20+49+49+5)

if i run the query from sql, this is what i should be getting
[image]

i notice that the Count number gets duplicated (7,7,20,20,49,49,5) instead of (7,20,49,5,10,27,13)

can anybody tell me what have i done wrong?

Comment: Why not just do it all in 1 stored proc / query? Don't see why you need to loop?

Comment: Your first query is open to sql injection.  Recommend using parameters for that query as you did in your second query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have called `getCases()` only once because inside it has a loop for each staff (*arraystaff*). Another thing, can you provide us a little more info regarding the problem? eg. sample records, desired output so we can more help you :)

**UPDATE 1**

move the `ds = New DataSet` before the For Loop, and *pass* the `Command Object` to the `DataAdapter Object`.

```
Sub getCases()
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        con.Open()
    End If

    ReDim arrdata(arrstaff.Length - 1, 0)

    ds = New DataSet
    For Me.i = 0 To arrstaff.Length - 1

        cmd = New SqlCommand("get_cases", con)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ename", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = arrstaff(i)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Yr", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddyear.SelectedValue
        cmd.Parameters.Add("month", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = m

        da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(ds)

        If Not IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("NoCase")) Then
            arrdata(i, 0) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("NoCase")
        End If

    Next

    cmd = New SqlCommand("delete from cases_Temp", con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```